# Will running next to a highway cause me to inhale more particulates?

Tags: exercise, lungs, breathing, inhalation

I'm wondering if running next to a highway will cause humans to inhale more [particulate matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particulates) and harmful substances.

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to health.SE! Are you looking for something specific? Otherwise, I fear this question is too broad.

Comment: Hi there, I've edited your question to be more specific to prevent it from being closed for being too broad. If you have any other particular concerns with running next to a highway, I recommend asking in a separate question. That way, people who respond know exactly what you're asking, otherwise, asking broad questions is really asking a lot.